# Eclipse: How to generate equals and hashCode using getters instead of fields?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to customize how Eclipse generates the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods forcing the usage of getters instead of acceding directly to fields?

Comment: Can you give an example where that would make sense?

Comment: A better alternative to using an auto-generated hashCode algorithm is [Objects.hash](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash-java.lang.Object...-).

Comment: when i want to compare 2 hibernate entity loaded via named query, eager properties are loaded only with getter and not with direct access to property